# How to replicate a Braze Canvas Webhook in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: webhooks, salesforce-marketing-cloud, braze

In efforts to migrate my current platform (Braze) to SFMC (Salesforce Marketing Cloud), I am required to replicate the Braze Canvas Webhooks in SFMC. How do I go about that.

I tried finding documentation but could not find anything fruitful.